# Use to_representation to combine fields from related models in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I've got the following models:-

```
class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    etc.

class Game(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    etc.

class GameMembership(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="memberships")
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name="memberships")
    available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I've created a ModelViewSet to return all the Players but I'd like to be able to, for each player in the list, return a list of their game memberships. I can do that, quite easily, but the data it returns looks like this:-

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "memberships": [
        {
            "available": True,
            "game": {
                "date": "a date",
                etc.
            }
        },
        {
            "available": False,
            "game": {
                "date": "a date",
                etc.
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but I'd like to hide the "memberships" aspect of my database from the API users and return something like this instead:-

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "games": [
        {
            "available": True,
            "date": "a date",
            etc.
        },
        {
            "available": False,
            "date": "a date",
            etc.
        }
    ]
},
```

So I want to take a field (or two) from the GameMembership model and combine it with all the fields from the Game model but crucially, I want it all in to one dictionary in the returned results. I know I can simply serialize Game on the GameMembershipSerializer, but that means that I'll be returning:-

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "games": [
        {
            "available": True,
            "game": {
                "date": "a date",
                etc.
            }
        },
        {
            "available": False,
            "game": {
                "date": "a date",
                etc.
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

which doesn't really make sense, as the user will have to access things like results['games'][1]['game'] which seems wrong.

I thought I could do it by using to_representation on the GameMembershipSerializer but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach without overriding `to_representation`, is to use a `SerializerMethodField` and do the processing there like this:

```py
class GameModelSerializer(models.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'


class PlayerModelSerializer(models.ModelSerializer):
    games = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'games')

    def get_games(self, player)
        return [{
            'available': membership.available,
            **GameModelSerializer(membership.game).data,
        } for membership in player.memberships.all()]
```

And to make sure that the serializer doesn't hit the db per membership just to get the game, you can prefetch the membership with the game selected like this:

```
Player.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('memberships', queryset=GameMembership.objects.select_related('game'))
)
```

**EDIT:**
You could also do:

```
    def get_games(self, player)
        return [{
            **GameMembershipSerializer(membership).data,
            **GameModelSerializer(membership.game).data,
        } for membership in player.memberships.all()]
```

if you want to reuse `GameMembershipSerializer`.

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that I'm going to have to add all the fields I want from GameMembership by hand, rather than using the GameMembershipSerializer that already exists for that model, which would be much easier.

Comment: Ah in that case you can change the line `'available': membership.available,` to `** GameMembershipSerializer(membership).data,`

Comment: Excellent - thanks for your help. In the end, I needed to use to_representation as this was an optionally expandable field (using drf-flex-fields) but this answer set me on my way to working that all out!

Answer (score 2):

For those that are interested in how I ended up solving this, I needed to use to_representation as it needed to be an expandable field (using drf-flex-fields). I also found that the following implementation was a lot quicker than the code mentioned above so I used this instead:-

```
# PlayerSerializer

games = GameMembershipGameSerializer(many=True)


class GameMembershipGameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GameMembership
        fields = ["available", "game"]

    def to_representation(self, membership):
        representation = super().to_representation(membership)
        game = representation.pop("game")

        for key in game:
            representation[key] = game[key]

        return representation
```